# Looking for developers to help me turn ideas into products

Tags: application-development, development, web-development

Can anyone suggest how I might go about looking for young developers who can help me turn linux-based ideas into products (initially unpaid)?

I am a Business Analyst not a coder and have a couple of workable ideas. I don't have the budget to pay but do have enough to fund hardware, software etc and would cut them in significantly if the products became reality. I don't think the dev effort would be too massive, more a case of bolting existing technologies together.

I am based in London so someone local would be best.

Can anyone suggest how I might search for someone who would be interested?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Programmers are human beings, they can't live without money . Implementing an idea is very difficult than creating random ideas

Answer (score 6):

Looking for unpaid developers this way is a bit unrealistic. You can always post to something like Guru.com but be expected to have to pay. If your looking for developers to start a open source project then try Sourceforge of freshmeat. However, most developers want to be paid one way or another. The open source projects I work on are those that I get benefit from.

Expecting someone to donate their time for nothing is a bit silly. Expecting that donation of effort to get *your* idea off the ground is not what open source is about.

If you have an idea that you think will benefit the community, then post the full idea to Sourceforge or Freshmeat, ask in language specific rooms on irc.freenode.net and start from there. But again if you think your going to get free development just to get your idea off the ground, your almost certainly mistaken. If you idea is Ubuntu specific then try http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/